# Indenting part of paragraph after \\ in a list

Tags: lists, indentation

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
A list:

\begin{itemize}
\item \texttt{abc def ghi}\\
This needs to be indented.
\item \texttt{jkl mno pqr}\\
This needs to me indented, too.
\item \texttt{stu vwx yz}\\
But this musn't be indented.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I need to indent a little a text after `\\` in `\item`. I need it not to be global change because some of texts (maybe in another list) must not be indented.

**EDIT:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{parsep=0pt,listparindent=\parindent}

\begin{document}
A list:
\begin{itemize}
\item \texttt{abc def ghi}

This needs to be indented.
\item \texttt{jkl mno pqr}

This needs to me indented, too. It is a very long text and I need it to be moved right, not only the first line.
\item \texttt{stu vwx yz}\\
But this musn't be indented.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I said earlier something different that I meant. I don't want an indent (that moves first line right). I want to move all lines right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Load the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package to change (follow-up) paragraph spacing and indentation inside lists, and in the text body use paragraphs (blank lines) instead of `\\` at the appropriate places.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{parsep=0pt,listparindent=\parindent}

\begin{document}

A list:

\begin{itemize}
\item \texttt{abc def ghi}

This needs to be indented.
\item \texttt{jkl mno pqr}

This needs to me indented, too.
\item \texttt{stu vwx yz}\\
But this musn't be indented.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: Your revised requirement can be solved by, e.g., using the `addmargin` environment of the `scrextend` package (part of [`KOMA-Script`](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{parsep=0pt,listparindent=\parindent}

\usepackage{scrextend}

\begin{document}

A list:

\begin{itemize}
\item \texttt{abc def ghi}

This needs to be indented.
\item \texttt{jkl mno pqr}

\begin{addmargin}[\parindent]{0pt}% optional: additional left margin, mandatory: additional margin
This needs to me indented, too. It is a very long text and I need it to be moved right, not only the first line.
\end{addmargin}
\item \texttt{stu vwx yz}\\
But this musn't be indented.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]